# An adverb which means "doing without understanding"

Tags: single-word-requests, adverbs

I'm trying to translate a sentence into English which is something like

"'What do you mean?' he -ly asked."

Of course I could say something like

"he asked, not understanding."

But I'm just curious if there's a single word which can be used here.

I don't think *confusedly* or *bewilderingly* works as their connotation is a bit too strong. The connotation should ideally be as literal as possible.

Comment: I'm puzzled why you need an adverb here, let alone an *-ly* one. After all, your alternative, *not understanding*, is modifying the subject here, not the predicate. It was the asker who was lacking understanding, not the asking. As such, it seems like you could use another participle or an adjective, even a prepositional phrase.

Comment: Even if the author overexplained that the question is a question, "What do you mean?" stands on its own. We translate *or apple or pear* into English by dropping a word. Otherwise, a forced Tom Swifty. If I had grown up in NY City, I'd ask "He asked, not understanding, because he could ask ... understanding?"

Comment: @tchrist I don't _need_ one I was just curious what the best it was possible to do with a single word in this structure was. Of course the default thing to do is just rephrase it to use multiple words.

Comment: **MODERATOR NOTE**: I've had to lock this question against comments because it's been drawing drive-bys who can't seem to stop themselves from violating SE policy by placing answers in comments.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I believe you are asking how to alter a conceptual structure of one subject (*he*) used with two verbs (*asked* and *did not understand*) to one subject (*he*) and one verb (*asked*) that uses an adverbial modifier to indicate that he did not understand.

In your sentence, *not understanding* is (if your preferred English grammar framework allows for such a thing) a [reduced adverb clause](https://www.thoughtco.com/reduced-adverb-clauses-1211106). In a sentence where you have the same subject in both a main clause and an adverb clause, you can reduce the adverb clause to avoid subject repetition:

> *“What do you mean?” **he** asked, because **he** did not understand.* →
> *“What do you mean?” **he** asked, not understanding.*

If you simply must have an adverb, perhaps *blankly* — in its sense of *without understanding* — would work:

> *“What do you mean?” **he** asked blankly.*

Here’s an example:

> “I did not know my brother was on the Monotah
> until he— he lay dying in my cabin,” she answered.
>     
>   He stared at her in amazement.
>        “I
> don’t understand,” he said blankly.
>        ”I did
> not understand then myself,” she said . . .
>  <sub>—[*Two Stolen
> Idols* by Frank L. Packard,
> 2019](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Two_Stolen_Idols/KTqMDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22he+said+blankly%22+understand&pg=PA140&printsec=frontcover)</sub>

Comment: I think blankly is quite a good answer, although the others were good as well. I think it has the most neutrality/lack of extra implications.

Comment: "Blankly" as in "without understanding" (or expression) is commonly used with "stare", whereas the meaning associated with speaking is [typically](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/blankly) "in every respect; totally; fully". To me, both roughly mean there isn't any "colour" or depth involved, which could mean looking without really seeing, or speaking without subtext or nuance, whereas saying something without understanding does typically come with the "depth" of confusion, uncertainty or curiosity. So "blankly" wouldn't fit too well here for me.

Answer (score 15):

In OP's context, *without understanding* doesn't mean *robotically* or *without thinking about it* - it means *unable to make sense of things*. Hence...

> *"What do you mean?"...* *(What does this mean? What's going on?)*
> [*...he asked **bemusedly***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22asked%20bemusedly%22)
> [*...he asked **bewilderedly***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22asked%20bewilderedly%22)

(Both those possibilities link to many written instances in Google Books)

Comment: “What do you mean?”, Tom asked, puzzled.

Comment: Excellent! But he *did* ask for an adverb. But, yeah. If I was a writer, and my "proofreader" suggested your version I'd grab it gratefully!  (I'd already have ruled out  "bewilderedly" all on my own! :)

Comment: Anyway, I already posted mine as an Answer because I thought it was being a bit lazy to just leave it as a comment under ***uncomprehendingly***. Perhaps *you* should do the decent thing and post yours as an Answer! :)

Comment: I've asked him why he says he needs an adverb, considering that his original *not understanding* which he discarded was no adverb to begin with—so I can't understand why he thinks he needs an adverb there in the first place. He's describing the actual person who is doing the asking, not the manner of his request!

Comment: It's an annoyingly vague context. I'm sure the OP must know the *exact* meaning of the sentence he's trying to translate. And if he's got the "job" of translating it into English, the implication is he should be able to be *precise* about the intended meaning. Using many words - many *sentences*, if necessary - so we don't have to guess what seems *likely*.

Answer (score 13):

Try **uncomprehendingly**. It works in many contexts such as yours.

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/uncomprehendingly)
> *uncomprehendingly*
> adverb
> without understanding something:
> *He listened uncomprehendingly to her technical explanations.*
> *She gazed at him uncomprehendingly when he questioned her.*

Comment: Or, perhaps, [*...he asked **bemusedly***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22asked+bemusedly%22). There it is in print, many times.

Comment: *“What do you mean?” he asked uncomprehendingly* is comparable to *“What do you mean?” he asked without understanding* — which doesn’t make much sense here.

Comment: @Tinfoil Hat Couldn't “What do you mean?” he asked blankly ['with _blankly_ in its sense of _without understanding_'] be considered equally redundant? I'd say yours works, though, as 'blankly' means 'without any understanding at all'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth — At the time of my comment, I think I was trying to suggest that when one “asks uncomprehendingly,” it means that they didn’t understand that (or what) they had asked — you know, like a senior moment or something.

Answer (score 6):

- “What do you mean?” he [asked, ***confused***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22asked%20confused%22&tbm=bks&sxsrf=AJOqlzUqxtiSmBO1e4iOvH9p4gO_z9HGsg:1674033108960&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1900,cd_max:1999&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjO2LSm49D8AhWMsKQKHXbnCuAQpwV6BAgBECM&biw=1118&bih=637&dpr=2.5).

Yes, confused is an adjective but it fits and it's idiomatic. Changing it into an adverb (*[confusedly](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/confusedly)*) would not work as well because it could also mean “in a confusing manner”.

Cambridge Dictionary defines *confused* as,

> *unable to think clearly or to understand something*:

Answer (score 3):

If the asker doesn't understand because it is a new concept being told, you can use the word `naively`.

> naively: in a way that shows a lack of experience, wisdom, or judgment (Oxford)

> "What do you mean?" he naively asked.

Answer (score 1):

It depends to some extent on the nature of action being undertaken.  If it were to do with listening to or reading something, then Anton's well illustrated suggestion would be the best.

If it were a politician taking an action without properly understanding its implications, it would be more likely that an adverb like *blindly*.

> Not thinking about **or understanding** what you are doing [Cambridge English Dictionary] -
> *they just blindly followed orders*

Comment: *“What do you mean?” he blindly asked.* How will that work in the OP’s context?

Comment: I think OP's "lack of understanding" implies *puzzlement*, as opposed to blindly following orders. You wouldn't "blindly" ask what's going on, as seems to be the likely sense of *What do you mean [by that]?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers:  I took the headline question "doing something without  question" literally.  Asking is a rather special case of doing.  Just about any adverb I can think of is going to look odd as a modifier for 'ask' in the context of a need for more information, except in the context of the question's being daft (because the answer was in plain sight), or infuriating/vexatious (because he always made a point of that sort of response) or cunning/perceptive (because he suspected the speaker had no idea what he was on about)...  But no one word would do for all these special cases.

Comment: The question itself is irritatingly imprecise - especially since I *assume* the OP speaks the language of the text he's translating, so he should know *exactly* what the context and required meaning is. Just because he can't think of a single-word English adverb for that sense doesn't mean he can't write as many sentences as necessary to tell us as much as he knows about the intended meaning. But actually, the question as phrased is a bit of a guessing game.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want "'What do you mean?' he mindlessly asked."

you could use "absent mindedly" if 2 words is ok.

Answer (score 1):

You've already selected 'blankly' as the answer, but my experience is that that the word 'cluelessly' would be more likely used in the context. The definition of "blankly" doesn't correspond to your description:

> "'What do you mean?' he -ly asked."

**'What do you mean?' he [cluelessly (MW)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cluelessly) asked.** Here you avoid the stronger terms 'confusedly' and its ilk, and at the same time stick with simpler speaking. 'Get a clue' is often heard as figurative language.

In addition, blankly tends to suggest a visual appraisal of someone's mental state, but you aren't using it dialog, you're using as a omniscient narrator when you are describing the mental state. If in the dialog the user was speaking to the person about that person's cluelessness, blankly might be a better fit. My personal experience is that people tend to use the world blankly to describe a face or state, not a mental state *per se*.

Answer (score 0):

rote, as in "We reconstructed the machine without understanding it's design by rote memorization during disassembly."

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Most answers, as @TinfoilHat notes, describe how you can describe the person rather than the actual statement. You want an adverb. If you would be fine with an adverbial phrase rather than a single word, might I suggest

> "What do you mean?" he asked, as if not understanding.

Especially if what you want to convey is how the question appears, rather than the actual state of understanding of the person in question, something like that might be the way to go. You could add more words and get a more precise statement, e.g.

> "What do you mean?" he asked, as if not having understood a word she had said.

> "What do you mean?" he asked happily, as if not understanding the graveness of the accusations just made against him.

Answer (score -1):

You might be able to use:

... "he asked oafishly."

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/oafishness

Depending on the context, of course.

Many readers would take this as some who was asking in an overbearing and uncaring manner.

Answer (score -1):

> 'What do you mean?' he *ignorantly* asked.

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ignorant):

> **ignorant**
> *adjective*
> ig·​no·​rant ˈig-n(ə-)rənt
> **1  a** : destitute of knowledge or education
>           an ignorant society
>         also : lacking knowledge or comprehension of the thing specified
>           parents ignorant of modern mathematics
>     **b** : resulting from or showing lack of knowledge or intelligence
>           ignorant errors
> **2** : UNAWARE, UNINFORMED

Answer (score -4):

Adjective

caricaturish (comparative more caricaturish, superlative most caricaturish)

```
Resembling a caricature
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).